# how to stop using livereload.js in my MEAN app

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, meanjs

I have moved my dev MEAN app from my laptop onto Azure.
I have set off of grunt's livereload flags to false, but, livereload.js is still being loaded, and its absolutelly killing me!
It take like 30 seconds(!) waiting for livereload.js
Is there a way to get rid of it altogether?

Comment: Can you show your grunt file?

Comment: Here  is the gruntfile:  https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/c99d4d62fe3f96e73e65

Comment: Did you remove/uncomment the livereload script tag from your index.html?

Comment: my app is based on mean.js boiler plate. all assets are defined in the config/env/all.js file, but livereload.js is not listed there.

Comment: Livereload script is in `app/views/layout.server.view.html`. Uncomment it, so that it is not requested.

Comment: brilliant! please, post as an answer. thank you!

Comment: Where can that be found in MEAN.js version 0.4.2? Is it possible to use livereload with gulp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to fully remove `livereload` in your app if running in `development` mode:

1. Disable it in `gruntfile` by giving `options.livereload = false` for your **watch** task.
2. Uncomment the script request from your html file. In your case, livereload is being requested by `app/views/layout.server.view.html`.