# How do I use livereload.js when my server is hosted?

Tags: networking, docker, google-cloud-platform, meanjs, livereload

I setup my development environment on a cloud server (why not, it's lovely!).

Specifically I am running my dev environment in google cloud with docker, forking the meanjs/mean GitHub and corresponding Dockerhub entry as a starting point.

I have mapped the port 3000 from my container where my server is running to port 80 on my cloud server where docker-engine is running. I also mapped the 35729 port to 35729 in same fashion.

See output of `$ sudo docker ps` (can't seem to put that table of long lines in a snippet, sorry I put it in a screenshot instead):
[output of `$ sudo docker ps`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur9Qj.png)

Now when I go to my website I gets stuck forever on liverload.js (seeing it in the browser console "Network" tab).
[livereload hanging forever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiHvs.png)

Please help 'cause this is driving me nuts!

Closely related to this question, but I want to use livereload not disable it: [how to stop using livereload.js in my MEAN app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585215/how-to-stop-using-livereload-js-in-my-mean-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like port 35729 isn't open.

```
$ nmap -p 35729 23.251.146.156

Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-08 09:34 EDT
Nmap scan report for 156.146.251.23.bc.googleusercontent.com (23.251.146.156)
Host is up (0.0043s latency).
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
35729/tcp filtered unknown
```

Are you sure that you've allowed port 35729 traffic? There could be something like `iptables` or some Google Cloud configuration that needs to be done to allow the traffic through.

It looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21068402/585787) gives a good step-by-step on opening a port in Google Cloud. I can't verify, since I don't use Google Cloud.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Followed the instructions in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065922/how-to-open-a-specific-port-such-as-9090-in-google-compute-engine and it is now working. Thanks!